# Trouble getting Hubot installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hubot

I have setup an EC2 instance based on Windows Server 2012. Here is what I'm seeing. Any ideas?

```
C:\sandbox\hubot>yo hubot
                 _____________________________
                /                             \
   //\              |      Extracting input for    |
  ////\    _____    |   self-replication process   |
 //////\  /_____\   \                             /
 ======= |[^_/\_]|   /----------------------------
  |   | _|___@@__|__
  +===+/  ///     \_\
   | |_\ /// HUBOT/\\
   |___/\//      /  \\
         \      /   +---+
          \____/    |   |
           | //|    +===+
            \//      |xx|

? Owner craigrow@hotmail.com
? Bot name tester
? Description A simple helpful robot for your Company
? Bot adapter (campfire)


C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\rx\dist\
rx.js:77
    throw e;
    ^
 true

C:\sandbox\hubot>
```

Blah, blah, blah, trying to get around the check that thinks I put too much code in here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem just now on Windows10.
I don't know why the problem is occurred, but I find

```
yo hubot --defaults
```

worked fine.

In your case

```
yo hubot --owner="craigrow@hotmail.com" --name="tester" --description="A simple helpful robot for your Company" --adapter=campfire
```

will work.

Comment: should be "yo hubot --defaults" (instead of "--default")